# Application closes when any menu closes

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I'm trying to make a very minimal app that just sits in the statusbar, responds to keyboard shortcuts and has a context menu. Whenever this menu closes either by an option selection or by the user clicking away, the application OnExit method gets called.

I've made a minimal version of this by creating a new WPF App on .NET7, deleted the `MainWindow.xaml`, and removed the reference to it in `App.xaml`, then this is the entire code in `App.xaml.cs`:

```
using System;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace CLP_MVP;
public partial class App : System.Windows.Application
{
    private readonly NotifyIcon _taskbarIcon = new();
    private readonly ContextMenu _contextMenu = new();
    protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnStartup(e);

        _taskbarIcon.Icon = ResourceIcons.clp;
        _taskbarIcon.Visible = true;
        _contextMenu.Items.Add(new MenuItem() { Header = "Test" });
        _taskbarIcon.Click += OpenMenu;
    }

    private void OpenMenu(object? sender, EventArgs e)
        => _contextMenu.IsOpen = true;

    protected override void OnExit(ExitEventArgs e)
        => base.OnExit(e);
}
```

I've had inconsistent results with clicking away (and I'd appreciate any insight here), but I've added one menu item with an unhandled click event which effectively closes the menu.

The call stack through the framework is:

```
>   CLP_MVP.dll!CLP_MVP.App.OnExit(System.Windows.ExitEventArgs e) Line 25  C#
    PresentationFramework.dll!System.Windows.Application.DoShutdown() Line 1582 C#
    PresentationFramework.dll!System.Windows.Application.ShutdownImpl() Line 2210   C#
    PresentationFramework.dll!System.Windows.Application.ShutdownCallback(object arg) Line 2198 C#
    WindowsBase.dll!System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(System.Delegate callback, object args, int numArgs) Line 103 C#
    WindowsBase.dll!System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.TryCatchWhen(object source, System.Delegate callback, object args, int numArgs, System.Delegate catchHandler) Line 36 C#
    WindowsBase.dll!System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.InvokeImpl() Line 540  C#
    WindowsBase.dll!MS.Internal.CulturePreservingExecutionContext.CallbackWrapper(object obj) Line 215  C#
    System.Private.CoreLib.dll!System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(System.Threading.ExecutionContext executionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback callback, object state) Line 183  C#
    WindowsBase.dll!MS.Internal.CulturePreservingExecutionContext.Run(MS.Internal.CulturePreservingExecutionContext executionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback callback, object state) Line 172 C#
    WindowsBase.dll!System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.Invoke() Line 412  C#
    WindowsBase.dll!System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.ProcessQueue() Line 2095    C#
    WindowsBase.dll!System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.WndProcHook(nint hwnd, int msg, nint wParam, nint lParam, ref bool handled) Line 2304   C#
    WindowsBase.dll!MS.Win32.HwndWrapper.WndProc(nint hwnd, int msg, nint wParam, nint lParam, ref bool handled) Line 295   C#
    WindowsBase.dll!MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.DispatcherCallbackOperation(object o) Line 429    C#
    WindowsBase.dll!System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(System.Delegate callback, object args, int numArgs) Line 103 C#
    WindowsBase.dll!System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.TryCatchWhen(object source, System.Delegate callback, object args, int numArgs, System.Delegate catchHandler) Line 36 C#
    WindowsBase.dll!System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.LegacyInvokeImpl(System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority priority, System.TimeSpan timeout, System.Delegate method, object args, int numArgs) Line 1339 C#
    WindowsBase.dll!MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.SubclassWndProc(nint hwnd, int msg, nint wParam, nint lParam) Line 341    C#
    [Native to Managed Transition]  
    [Managed to Native Transition]  
    WindowsBase.dll!System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.PushFrameImpl(System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherFrame frame) Line 2138 C#
    PresentationFramework.dll!System.Windows.Application.RunDispatcher(object ignore) Line 2407 C#
    PresentationFramework.dll!System.Windows.Application.RunInternal(System.Windows.Window window) Line 1695    C#
    CLP_MVP.dll!CLP_MVP.App.Main() Line 53  C#
```

Any help or thoughts on this would be appreciated. I assume it has something to do with early application lifecycle termination. As there are no 'visible' elements (other than the statusbar icon, which comes from a different framework), the application handler just terminates execution to avoid a zombie process. If this assumption is correct, I'd appreciate any thoughts on how to avoid this.

I have tried to use `Hardcodet.Wpf.TaskbarNotification`, with exactly the same results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, WPF apps will call an implicit shutdown when all of their windows close.  Try setting `ShutdownMode="OnExplicitShutdown"` in the App.Xaml file.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.application.shutdownmode

Be sure to add a way to shutdown manually.

Comment: Perfect, thanks! I have an Exit button in this menu that calls Current.Shutdown(), which I believe is the correct way to do this.